# What does "That means there is no sort of exchange to be made with the country's debtors" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean Venezuela has nothing to pay the creditors/bondholders?

> Observers need to comprehend the level to which the economy has imploded: "There is no economic plan," he explains. Oil production is declining sharply, and there is currently no value – with close to zero imports halting most production in the country – being created in the economy. **That means there is no sort of exchange to be made with the country's debtors**: "there is no future for bondholders [under the Maduro regime]," he says."

Source: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/business/2017/11/14/no-future-bond-holders-venezuela-staggers-default/

Comment: It means that Venezuela currently has no resources (either financial or natural) that can be used to pay the country's debt. Bondholders are running the risk of not being repaid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A debtor must have some valuable *medium of exchange* to pay its creditors.  Venezuela, whose economy depends on oil exports, currently has nothing of value.  This means that these creditors -- the "bondholders" -- are not likely to have their investment repaid.